# Oracle Case Statement Along with XMLElement is giving different output on each execution

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xml-db

This is the oracle query I am trying to execute which is giving different output on each execution. For the first execution it is giving the correct `xml` and all subsequent request it is returning null. Also, the scary thing is when I change the `xml` element name from `"PHONE"` to `"PHONE1"`, it again gives the output for the first time only, and `NULL` for subsequent request.

Also, if i hardcode the value of `CLI_PHONENUMBER` (the same value which is present in the table), it always gives the correct output.

```
SELECT          
    CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(CLI_PHONENUMBER,'[^0-9]+', '') IS NOT NULL
     AND CLI_PHONENUMBER <>'000000000000000'
    THEN XMLELEMENT("PHONE",
           XMLELEMENT("PHONETYPECODE",
               CASE
               WHEN regexp_like( REGEXP_REPLACE(CLI_PHONENUMBER,'[^0-9]+', ''), '^02[0-9]+')
               THEN 'MOB'
               ELSE 'BUSN' END),
           XMLELEMENT("AREACODE", NULL),
           XMLELEMENT("COUNTRYCODE",'64'),
           XMLELEMENT("PHONENUMBER", REGEXP_REPLACE(CLI_PHONENUMBER,'[^0-9]+', '')),
           XMLELEMENT("PRIMARYFLAG",NULL)
         )
     END
  FROM CLI_CLIENT
 WHERE CLI_COMPANY = 'AON'
   AND CLI_BRANCH = 'WTP'
   AND CLI_CLIENTNUMBER = '05QSZ';
```

Comment: Give us some sample data please

Comment: 0124 525353 - Here is one sample data..basically the phone numbers are stored in this field..due to some junk data imported from another system..i have put a validation that only numerical data should be selected..an only if a valid data exists, the xml should be generated..

Comment: I can't see any sample data

Comment: @pablomatico - The column contains the phone numbers like 0124 525353 or +91 - 242324  323.

Comment: It's working for me with those numbers